# Why does mypy fail with "incompatible type" in Enum classmethod?

Tags: python, mypy

In my Enum, i have defined a classmethod for coercing a given value to an Enum member. The given value may already be an instance of the Enum, or it may be a string holding an Enum value.
In order to decide whether it needs conversion, i check if the argument is an instance of the class, and only pass it on to int() if it is not. At which point – according to the type hints for the argument 'item' – it must be a string.

The class look like this:

```
T = TypeVar('T', bound='MyEnum')

class MyEnum(Enum):
    A = 0
    B = 1

    @classmethod
    def coerce(cls: Type[T], item: Union[int, T]) -> T:
        return item if isinstance(item, cls) else cls(int(item))
```

mypy fails with:

> error: Argument 1 to "int" has incompatible type "Union[str, T]";
> expected "Union[str, bytes, SupportsInt, SupportsIndex,
> _SupportsTrunc]"

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because **int** cannot be constructed from **Enum**. From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) of `int(x)`

> If x is not a number or if base is given, then x must be a **string**,
> **bytes**, or **bytearray** instance representing an integer literal in radix
> base

So to make it work you can make your Enum inherit from str

```
class MyEnum(str, Enum):
    A = 0
    B = 1
```

Or use [IntEnum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.IntEnum)

```
class MyEnum(IntEnum):
    A = 0
    B = 1
```

Edit: The question why `isinstance` doesn't narrow `T` type enough still left. Couldn't find any prove of my theory, but my (hopefully logical) explanation is - T is bounded to `MyEnum` so it's `MyEnum` and any subclass of it. If we have subclass scenario, `isinstance(item, MyEnumSubclass)` won't exclude case when item is just `MyEnum` class. If we use `MyEnum` directly in typing, problem will disappear.

```
    @classmethod
    def coerce(cls: t.Type["MyEnum"], item: t.Union[int, T]) -> "MyEnum":
        return item if isinstance(item, cls) else cls(int(item))
```

Comment: Wouldn't `if isinstance(item, cls)` serve as a type guard to avoid constructing an `int` from an instance of `MyEnum`?

Comment: @kosciej16 no, it does in fact work, if you call with a stringified version of one the intsavailable. MyEnum.coerce('0') -> <MyEnum.A: 0>

Comment: Deriving from IntEnum however, does pacify mypy about it and seems an elegant solution. still don't completely understand why the "guard and cast" approach is so upsetting.

Comment: After some trials with mypy stuff and `reveal_type` I think I found an explanation.

Comment: Another thing that works along the same line of reasoning is a method signature of `def coerce(cls: Type['MyEnum'], item: Union[str, 'MyEnum']) -> 'MyEnum':` and a return value of `return item if isinstance(item, MyEnum) else cls(int(item))`